# How do I get smooth transition between show / hide using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a select list with cities and a list of shopping malls.
Selecting a city, will show shopping malls for that city.

My "problem" is that the transition between hiding shopping malls for one city and showing for another, it not smooth. It "bumpy".

You can see what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/egUHN/12/

What is the best way to achieve a smooth transition?
I've tried using show/hide as well, but it does not help.

**UPDATE**
@Zanfa came up with an excellent solution by the use of `[promise().done()][1]`.

```
$('.city_list .city').fadeOut('normal').promise().done(function() {
    jQuery('.city_list .' + shmall_selected_city).fadeIn('normal');
});
```

I will test this later.

Comment: Are you able to change the html? i.e. do you generate it or do you get it from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have individual li's for each city and each one is placed below the other. Your best bet is to fix this with CSS, by adding:

```
.city_list .city { 
    position: absolute;
    display: none; 
}
```

Only problem is that your cities with more than one mall will be bunched together, you could fix this by changing your last jQuery line (fadeIn) to:

```
var count = 15;
jQuery('.city_list .' + shmall_selected_city).each(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeIn('normal');
    jQuery(this).css('top',count + 'px');
    count += 15;
});
```

Comment: .each takes a function (element,counter) so you could get rid of that variable and do $(element).css('top,15*counter + 'px');

Comment: @Serj - Thanks, that worked. See the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/egUHN/14/. +1 to @Emyr for shortening the code (it's `index` and not `counter`)

Comment: @Steven oh my god how complex solution. Much easier to just do http://jsfiddle.net/egUHN/18/

Comment: @Steven it's just a two-parameter closure so you can call them whatever you like. :-p Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just do `hide()` and `fadeIn()` instead of `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`. Using `hide()` and `fadeIn()` looks smooth and good. The code will become much complicated if you make it with `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`, and very few people would notice.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/egUHN/8/

Make it simple!

Answer (score 1):

You could try absolute positioning the `<a>` elements in the upper left corner:

```
.city_list { 
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
}

a {
    /* ... */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

That would put all the links in one place so there wouldn't be any jumping around during the transitions. During the transition, the new element would be fading in while the old one was fading out and they'd be overlapping during the fading.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tv9NA/

---

You have some cities with multiple links and just doing the above leaves them all stacked on top of each. That's probably not going to make anyone very happy but maybe if you wrap a `<div>` around your links, move the positioning to the `<div>`, and the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` the `<div>`. Or put each block of `<li>` elements in their own absolutely positioned `<ul>` and fade the whole lists in and out as needed.

Comment: That would work if you only have one line. But some cities have many shopping malls. Try selecting Oslo after having a city with just one sh.mall. The result is all lines are stacked on one line :)

Comment: @Steven: Is the same thing happening with "Førde"? Could you wrap a `<div>` around them and then fade the `<div>` in/out and put the absolute position on that? A smaller HTML sample might be easier to work with :)

Comment: he,he. I've cleaned up the code now. I also though I could wrap it in div's. The problem is that I can't wrap them in div's, because the list is sorted by shopping mall name, and not by city.

Comment: @Steven: Regroup the malls by city. You can do that on the server or do it in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the html, consider putting the lists of shipping centres into a hidden div with a class `lists` or `data` and cloning from there into your `.city_list` div on select change.

See http://jsfiddle.net/rob_cowie/qDFKn/24/